# xcodebuild -target -xcconfig doesn't work for react-native project

Tags: ios, xcode, jenkins, react-native, continuous-integration

When I am running the command `xcodebuild -target targetName -xcconfig configName.xcconfig` I have the following errors:

`clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/azghibarta/Documents/WorkFolder/ReactNativeApps/eezam/node_modules/react-native/React/build/Release-iphoneos/libReact.a'
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/azghibarta/Documents/WorkFolder/ReactNativeApps/eezam/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ActionSheetIOS/build/Release-iphoneos/libRCTActionSheet.a'
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/azghibarta/Documents/WorkFolder/ReactNativeApps/eezam/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Geolocation/build/Release-iphoneos/libRCTGeolocation.a'
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/azghibarta/Documents/WorkFolder/ReactNativeApps/eezam/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Image/build/Release-iphoneos/libRCTImage.a'
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/azghibarta/Documents/WorkFolder/ReactNativeApps/eezam/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LinkingIOS/build/Release-iphoneos/libRCTLinking.a'
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/azghibarta/Documents/WorkFolder/ReactNativeApps/eezam/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Network/build/Release-iphoneos/libRCTNetwork.a'
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/azghibarta/Documents/WorkFolder/ReactNativeApps/eezam/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Settings/build/Release-iphoneos/libRCTSettings.a'
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/azghibarta/Documents/WorkFolder/ReactNativeApps/eezam/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Text/build/Release-iphoneos/libRCTText.a'
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/azghibarta/Documents/WorkFolder/ReactNativeApps/eezam/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Vibration/build/Release-iphoneos/libRCTVibration.a'
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/azghibarta/Documents/WorkFolder/ReactNativeApps/eezam/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/WebSocket/build/Release-iphoneos/libRCTWebSocket.a'`

When I am running the command `xcodebuild -schema schemaName` all is working fine.
Finally .. I need to change the config schema for the build (dev / prod etc) as Jenkins job, and that it's possible only with the first command that gives error. I know about Xcode Plugin for Jenkins, but I want to use my own build script.